# Error when performing an upgrade in Debian 9

Tags: debian

Even though I am logged in as root, below is the conflict I am getting when trying to perform an upgrade :

```
root@:/home/frederic# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-headers-4.9.0-3-amd64 (4.9.30-2+deb9u3) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
Error! You must be root to use this command.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-headers-4.9.0-3-amd64.postinst line 11.
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-4.9.0-3-amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64 (4.9.30-2+deb9u3) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
Error! You must be root to use this command.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-amd64:
 linux-image-amd64 depends on linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64; however:
  Package linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-4.9.0-3-amd64
 linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64
 linux-image-amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

To me, it seems that there is an issue with the **dkms** package but when I try to reinstall it, It's not better :

```
root@:/home/frederic# apt-get install --reinstall dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/74.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 142800 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../archives/dkms_2.3-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.3-2) over (2.3-2) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.9.0-3-amd64 (4.9.30-2+deb9u3) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
Error! You must be root to use this command.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-headers-4.9.0-3-amd64.postinst line 11.
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-4.9.0-3-amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up dkms (2.3-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Setting up linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64 (4.9.30-2+deb9u3) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
Error! You must be root to use this command.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-amd64:
 linux-image-amd64 depends on linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64; however:
  Package linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-4.9.0-3-amd64
 linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64
 linux-image-amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Are _actually_ root? `id -u` should output a zero.

Comment: I am : 
root@:/home/frederic# id -u
0

Comment: Why are you using dkms?

Comment: Great question :-) I don't even know myself, isn't it a necessary built-in package ?

Comment: [out of curiosity](http://aptosid.com/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=18545), what's the output of `echo $UID` ?

Comment: please add the output of "ls -la /var/lib/dkms"

Comment: echo $UID
1000
ls -la /var/lib/dkms
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep  1 11:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 46 root root 4096 Aug 30 16:18 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    6 Aug 31  2016 dkms_dbversion

Comment: if that directory listing is complete, uninstall dkms, it it not doing anything

Comment: excellent. added an answer.

Comment: Uninstalling `dkms` isn't an answer to this issue. At best it is a workaround, and not a good one. I recommending finding out why this error is being thrown.

Comment: BTW, when you ran `apt-get upgrade`, apt said "3 not fully installed or removed." You should fix this issue first before doing anything else. But maybe the upgrade caused the problem in the first place.

Comment: The upgrade caused the problem in the first place

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for you having errors with `dkms`, I advise as a first course of action, to check it out whether really `dkms` is needed, before wasting time investigating the core root of the error.

Normally, `dkms` is used to (re)compile/install automagically additional modules, not belonging to the default kernel after installing a package with a new kernel version. For instance, `sysdig` modules or realtek drivers, or in old Debian versions, VMware vmtools modules.

As we have seen from the request,  `ls -la /var/lib/dkms` does not have additional modules to compile in there (normally (sub)directories with source code).

Therefore, we know dkms is not doing anything useful in this machine.

```
ls -la /var/lib/dkms
total 12 
drwxr-xr-x 2  root root 4096 Sep  1 11:53 . 
drwxr-xr-x 46 root root 4096 Aug 30 16:18 .. 
-rw-r--r-- 1  root root    6 Aug 31 2016 dkms_dbversion
```

As such the advised course of action is to uninstall it, with the command:

```
sudo aptitude purge dkms
```